# Keynote Presentation locking

Tags: ipad, bluetooth, keynote

Is there a way to lock an iPad, playing a Keynote presentation, in presentation mode so that you cannot access edit mode at all?  We have a presentation which plays during a tour and if one of our guides, while getting the presentation set up, gets into edit mode, they can press our Bluetooth remote and it will add slides.  We use guided access mode once we are in the presentation we want, but there are two different presentations on the iPad and they need the ability to switch back and forth between presentations, but never the ability to add slides or edit the presentation.

How can the Keynote presentation itself be limited to read-only?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution:

Using **Collaboration**, the author can create the presentations on a different device, the share the presentations as a view only type.

Using a private Apple ID to create the presentations, different from the one set up on the iPad, would allow for more control of the presentations themselves without limiting the use of the iPad.

---

[image: Collaboration options on iOS]